# date format check for inputted date python

Tags: python, validation, date

I'm finding trouble trying to ensure that the user has inputted the data in a specific format with a type of validation check.
Something that keeps the user in a while loop until the date entered is in `dd/mm/yy`  format.

I have tried this with the

```
time.strptime(" %d/%m/%y")
```

but I couldn't seem to make it compare this format with the user's format.

(python newbie)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mix full year and abbreviated months you could check:

```
from datetime import datetime

while True:
    try:
        inp = input("Please enter date in format yyyy/mon/dd. ie 2015/feb/05")
        dte = datetime.strptime(inp,"%Y/%b/%d")
        break
    except ValueError as e:
        print("Invalid format")
print(dte)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import time

valid = False
while not valid:
    date_str = input("Date:")
    try:
        time.strptime(date_str, "%d/%m/%y")
        valid = True
    except ValueError:
        valid = False

print(date_str)
```

Example:

```
Date:22/01/2015
Date:22/01/15
22/01/15
```

Comment: what if the user enters `01/01/15` how can you know which is which for sure?

Comment: Well, of course, the input statement should be more precise and say it's day / month / year or dd/mm/yy. But it's not really a programming issue there.

Comment: but that still won't mean the user will input in correct order, the only way to be sure is to mix names and digits. Just because it works does not mean the user has the actual order correct

Comment: I fully understand your point and I agree. But I'm only answering to OP's question: « something that keeps the user in a while loop until the date entered is in dd/mm/yy format ».